# PostgreSQL Convert timestamptz

Tags: postgresql, timezone, timestamp-with-timezone

I have timestamps stored in a PostgreSQL table with datatype `timestamp with time zone`.  I understand they're really stored with UTC, but the database is set to US Central (CST / CDT).  All records were not originally US Central timestamps - some where from other US timezones.  When querying, I would like to identify the correct original timezone, based on the city, and convert the timestamps back to the source timezone.  This part is solved with a set of manually-created lookup tables.

What I'm stuck on is knowing when to convert to *Standard* vs. *Daylight* versions of the timezones.  In the US, Standard -> Daylight on the 2nd Sunday in March at 0200 hrs (which immediately becomes 0300).  On the 1st Sunday in November, Daylight -> Standard at 0200, which immediately becomes 0100.  The first transition is easy (`date > spring_forward` & `hour > 2`).

The second transition is hard, however, since there are essentially 2 records for 0100 on that day; the 1st 0100 for CDT, then the 2nd (fallen back) 0100 for CST.  Obviously, I want to convert the duplicated 0100 as Standard, but not the 1st, but I'm unsure how to do this without some complicated counting query.  This issues seems to have been solved in python with "generic" timezones, such as "Pacific" which encompasses both PST & PDT.  I see nothing like this for PostgreSQL, though: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.2/static/timezones.html.

For a timestamp, given that I know the original city, how can I generically convert the timezone to the correct (Standard vs. Daylight) timezone?

Comment: I would still stick to selecting timestamptz at time zone '*zone name from your look up table*'...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to worry about daylight savings time yourself, PostgreSQL has all the smarts. Use the `AT TIME ZONE` syntax.

To convert a `timestamp with time zone` to Chicago time:

```
SELECT '2017-12-03 00:00:00 UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'America/Chicago';

      timezone       
---------------------
 2017-12-02 18:00:00
(1 row)
```

The result is a `timestamp without time zone`. As you can see, the timestamp was correctly converted to daylight savings time.

You can find the list of supported time zones in the catalog view `pg_timezone_names`.

Comment: I see that this does work, though 'America/Chicago' is not listed in the documentation as a time zone.  Can you please point me to where this (and other) names are documented?

Comment: I have added it to the answer.